# Select COUNT where field NOT NULL, for each field of the table

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I have a table with a lot of fields, and I need to return the COUNT of NOT NULL for each field.

I make a loop in PHP and I execute 1 request by field...

```
$result = array();
$champs = array("field1", "field2", "field3", "field4", "field5", "field6", "field7", "field8", "field9", "field10", "field11", "field12", "field13", "field14", "field15", "field16", "field17", "field18", "field19", "field20");

foreach ($champs as $value) {
    $and = empty($filtroAdd) ? "$value IS NOT NULL" : "AND $value IS NOT NULL";

    $requete = "SELECT COUNT($value)
                FROM my_table
                WHERE $filtroAdd $and";
    $r = $db->query($requete)->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

    $result[$value] = $r[0];
}

print_r( $result );
```

I think it is not the better way, and we surely can return the same final result with a single postgreSQL request ?!

Thanks for help

Comment: `COUNT(<column_name or expression>)` already excludes `NULL` values. See http://www.techonthenet.com/postgresql/functions/count.php , so you can have a single `SELECT` with multiple `COUNT(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a single query:

```
SELECT COUNT(field1), COUNT(field2), COUNT(field3), . . .
FROM my_table;
```

There is no need to do a separate query for each field.  `COUNT(<field>)` returns the number of rows with non-NULL values in that column.

If you want the number of *different* values, then use `COUNT(DISTINCT)`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT field1), COUNT(DISTINCT field2), COUNT(DISTINCT field3), . . .
FROM my_table;
```

You can also embed `CASE` logic, if you like.  I usually do this using `SUM()`:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN field1 > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
```